# Where to put JQuery code in a Web Content Form and how to make it work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a web content form whose master page is a nested master page. I want to put JQuery code in this page, but it is not accepting the Script tags. In this page, I only have:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

</asp:Content>
```

I also want the the JQuery code to fire through my ASP button click as opposed to the traditional HTML button. Will it recognize ASP button click event?

**Edited:**
It is still not working. I tried the suggestions as given below. I did following changes in my code:

**Master Page:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/main.css" runat="server" />
    <link id="Link1" rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/selectCompany.css" type="text/css" runat="server" />
        <link type="text/css" href="AJAX/jqueryUI/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AJAX/jqueryUI/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AJAX/jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

**Changes in content form:**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $(this).attr('id').match('btnNew2').click(function() {
                   alert("Hello world!");
               });
           });
     </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContentArea" runat="server">

 <div id="divHeadings" runat="server" class="TopBar">NEW COMPANY</div>
              <div id="divEntryForm" runat="server"  class="CompanyEntryForm">
                  <asp:Button ID="btnNew2" runat="server" Text="New" 
                CssClass="BtnStyle" />&nbsp;
              </div>
```

**Edited**

I made the changes as suggested by @Akram and @pumkin, still the JQuery code is not responding to any events. I have updated Master Page code above.

Someone suggested me to use FireBug to identify the actual ID name of the control. Though FireBug I detected the ID of one of the controls to be:

ctl00_MasterContentArea_btnNew2

I replaced the JQuery code with the changes as below, but it is still not showing the alert box:

**Code in the Web Content Form**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() 
           {
               $('input[id*=\'ctl00_MasterContentArea_btnNew2\']').val().click(function() 
                {
                   alert("Hello world!");
               });
           });
       </script>
</asp:Content>
```

It is simply not recognizing the Click or any other Events. I guess the control is not reaching the above code area.

Comment: Strange it should work. what do you mean by not allowing ?. You can call the Jquery method via onClientClick of the button server control

Comment: are there any error on the page is you do F12 on IE or inspect eleemtn in chrome? Any red cross or yellow !? try and debug the code- does simple alert work jsut for test to see if syntax is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `ContentPlaceHolder` in your master page `<head>` section :

```
<head runat="server">    
   <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/main.css" runat="server" />    
   <link id="Link1" rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/selectCompany.css" 
      type="text/css" runat="server" />    
   <link type="text/css" 
      href="AJAX/jqueryUI/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css"
      rel="Stylesheet" />        
   <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="AJAX/jqueryUI/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>              
   <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="AJAX/jqueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>   

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">        
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In the page place the associated `Content`:

```
<asp:Content ID="head" ContentPlaceHolderID="headPlaceHolder" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Place your page scripts and styles inside this `Content`.

Comment: @RPK: Clear the ContentPlaceHolder in the master page. Place the scripts and styles inside the head but outside the ContentPlaceHolder.

Comment: @Akram: It was like that previously. The scripts were in the head tag outside of ContentPlaceHolder. It is still not working.

Comment: @RPK: Previously, you had an empty ContentPlaceHolder for the main section of your page!!

Comment: @RPK I've edited the answer. That is exactly how the head section must be in your master page ..

Comment: Somehow it worked, when I added the reference of JQuery files inside the Content Head area of the Web Content Form and also changed as pumkin suggested: ('[id$=MyButton]').click(function(){ alert('button clicked'); });
Thanks to both.

Answer (score 1):

Like Akram S Answered you need to put the headContent place holder if you want to put jQuery in the nesterd masterpage.

You can use the normal asp button if you want just disable callback function on it and give it an ID.

Using jQuery in nestermaster pages you will have to find the ASP ID as masterpages append some things to the id always and there are several ways to attach to these buttons.

```
$('[id$=MyButton]').click(function(){ alert('button clicked'); });
```

OR - Use codebehind attaching <%vb.variable%>

```
$("#<%=page.MyButton%>").click();
```

OR - A less efficient way but always works- Don use #. Selects first matched ID from top.

```
$(this).attr('id').match('MyButton').click(function() { });
```

--Edit

These are directly out of my website that works with a masterpage.

Check box Value on Master page

```
$("input[name*='myCheckBox']").attr('checked')
```

Textbox Value on MasterPage

```
$('input[name*=\'textGcal1\']').val()
```

Comment: I set the AutoPostBack=false for the TextBox but still not working.

Comment: Check my answer again- after the Edit. That has to work. because it works on my masterpages.

Comment: Not responding to any events. I tried to those two ways also. How to determine the ID name of any ASP TextBox at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the script code inside the form tag in Site.Master page and outside the ContentPlaceHolder tag.

```
<form runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[id*=\'ctl00_MasterContentArea_btnNew2\']').val().click(function () {
                alert("Hello world!");
            });
        });
   </script> </form>
```